# Angular google map ui-gmap-search-box not exiting

Tags: angularjs

In my app once, i click into the angular maps `<ui-gmap-search-box>` the mobile keyboard pops up which is fine. The text input is in the $template cache: `<input id="pac-input" class="pac-controls" type="text" placeholder="Search">`

The problem is if i click out of there and don't want to search anymore, every time i click the map the mobile keyboard pops up.

How do i stop the mobile keyboard poping once i exit the search text input?

Thanks

Comment: `every time i click the map the mobile keyboard pops up` isn't that what you want to happen? Maybe the map is too big and you need to make it smaller on mobiles.

Comment: No, if i click the map i want the marker to go there. The text box is in the upper right hand side of the map and after inspecting the element in only covers the text input area. Clicking outside the map clears the cursor from the text input but not clicking on map